# Normalization depending on Parameter in ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following differential equation numerically:

```
N0 := 1;
DN := 0.5
L := 1;
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[x] == -y[x]*(x - a)/(N0 -DN*HeavisideTheta[x+L/2]+DN*HeavisideTheta[x - L/2]), y[0] == 1}, y, {x, -5, 5},     {a}]
```

This works very well. However I want to normalize these functions based on the integral under the curve for different parameters.

```
N0 := NIntegrate[Evaluate[Table[y[a][x] /. sol, {a, -2, 2, 0.5}]], {x, -5, 5}]
```

How can I automate this process, so that I can use a very fine grid for `a`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a recursive method? Initiate N0, calculate sol with this one in order to update N0, calculate sol again etc. until it converges and turns out to be self-consistent?

Comment: Not really. Basically I want to calculate N0[a] for different values of a. Divide the solution for different values of a by N0[a] and then integrate with respect to a for a fixed point x.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this pParametricNDSolve and I'm not sure if I get your purpose intirely. But I think what you are after can be accomplished by realizing that Table is kind of a for-loop, so you can put it outwards and then something like Table[Na = NIntegrate[Evaluate [y[a][x] /. sol], {x, -5, 5}];
 ynorm[a][x] = y[a][x]/Na, {a, -2, 2, 0.5}]

Comment: @Wouter thanks! I will try it out.